# How does Android assist work internally?

Tags: android, google-assist-api

I have read the documentation and it says,

> The matching between the current user context and potential actions
>   displayed in the overlay window (shown in step 3 in Figure 1) is
>   specific to the assistant’s implementation. However, consider adding
>   deep linking support to your app. The assistant will typically take
>   advantage of deep linking. For example, Google Now uses deep linking
>   and App Indexing in order to drive traffic to destination apps.

Other than deep linking and App Indexing, is there any alternate way, I can utilise user's contextual information received as an instance of the [AssistStructure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/assist/AssistStructure.html) in [onHandleAssist()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/voice/VoiceInteractionSession.html#onHandleAssist(android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.assist.AssistStructure,%20android.app.assist.AssistContent)) and screenshot through [onHandleScreenshot()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/voice/VoiceInteractionSession.html#onHandleScreenshot(android.graphics.Bitmap)).

Specifically, I want to know two things,

1) How does android assist work internally? Does it use google search service and provide answers? Does it use Google public search ontology?

2) Can we build a custom ontology that provides us the assist results the way we require with a custom solution?

Any insight would be of great help.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am expecting your inputs here.